# Unable to run exec for jsch

Tags: unix, ssh, jsch

When i am running exec for grep using the public key it is failing with below error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
```

When I run the same thing using my username password it is working fine

Following is my connect and run command method

```
    public boolean validateUser(String host) throws Exception {
            logger.info("Validating user " + this.getUserId());
            String user = getUserId();

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            try {

                session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
                session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
                jsch.setKnownHosts("~/.ssh/known_hosts");
                jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");
                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.connect(30000);                 
                session.connect();

                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.info("Exception" + e);
                throw e;
            }

        }

    public StringBuilder runCmd(String cmnd) throws JSchException, IOException {
             logger.info("connecting to server");
            Channel channel = this.session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(cmnd);
            channel.setXForwarding(true);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setOutputStream(System.out);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect(500000);
            channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            BufferedInputStream bufIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {

                while (bufIn.available() > 0) {
                    int i = bufIn.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    sb.append((new String(tmp, 0, i)));

                }
                logger.info("channelStatus is " + channel.isClosed());
                logger.info("Exit status = " + channel.getExitStatus());
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    bufIn.close();
                    break;
                }
                while (channel.getExitStatus() == -1){
                    try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
                 }
                logger.info("Closing unix connection");
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            return sb;
        }
```

Comment: Can you do this in PuTTY? (or other SSH client) In PuTTY, go to *Connection > SSH* and enter your `cmnd`. Login with private key. Would it start the command?

Comment: Also did you check SSH server log file?